# Jinja formatting in IntelliJ community edition

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I've been looking for a plugin/way to format Jinja files in IntelliJ community edition. I looked into using the Python template languages, but seems like that's available only in the professional edition.

I tried to use the YAML/Ansible plugin, but that doesn't seem to be the best. Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it exist. in fact this is a plus of [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/template-languages.html), the jetbrain python IDE.

So you can maybe use it on IDEA ultimate but not on the comunity there is a [topic](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206594815-jinja2-code-formatting) on jetBrain Suport website.